# How can i create an custom post template for an specific post category?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

How can i create an custom post template for an specific post category in Wordpress?

Comment: is this for a single custom post type view and the built in `category` taxonomy?

Answer (score 4):

this the default template priority structure for categories:

category-slug.php
category-ID.php
category.php
archive.php
index.php

so if your category slug is "car", you can add file named category-car.php

make sure you resave permalinks after adding the file, if it doest work :)

[more details here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files)

Answer (score 4):

I'll add this answer since it's not clear if you are asking about a category archive template or a single custom post template.

To change single post templates, use the [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) filter and check if the post is in a specific category. There are a number of [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) you can use to determine what you're viewing and what terms an object has assigned.

In this example we check if it is a single post of type `foo` which has category `bar` assigned.

```
function add_posttype_slug_template( $single_template ){
    if( is_singular( 'foo' ) && in_category( 'bar' ) ){
        $single_template = locate_template( 'my-custom-template.php' );
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'add_posttype_slug_template' );
```